# Most "rusty" way to wrap Rustson responses and avoid duplicated traits?

Tags: rust, serde

I'm learning Rust, but I'm not sure about the most elegant or "rusty" way of doing some things:

I'm retrieving data from an API that, on some endpoints returns a JSON object (`{ value: "resource A" }`), but in other occasions, it returns a JSON object wrapped by another object (`{ error: false, data: { value: "resource A" } }`).

I'm using [Restson](https://github.com/spietika/restson-rust) to retrieve that data.

My question is: what is the most elegant way to deal with different responses? I don't know how to use some kind of abstract `Response` that could accept both kind of JSON responses.

I mean, in this case I'm implementing 2 traits, but both of them have the same content, so, to me, it smells like there is something wrong there.

This is a simplified example, so typos could exist:

```
use restson::{RestPath, RestClient, Error};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Response<T> {
    error: bool,
    data: T
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct ResourceA {
    value: String,
}

// HERE: How do I remove this duplication?  
impl<'a> RestPath<(&'a str, String)> for ResourceA {
    fn get_path(params: (i8, String, &str)) -> Result<String, Error> {
        let (resource, id) = params;
        Ok(format!("{}/{}", resource, id))
    }
}
impl<'a, T> RestPath<(&'a str, String)> for Response<T> {
    fn get_path(params: (&str, String)) -> Result<String, Error> {
        let (resource, id) = params;
        Ok(format!("{}/{}", resource, id))
    }
}

pub struct Client {
    client: RestClient,
}

impl Client {
    pub fn new() -> Client {
        Client {
            client: RestClient::new("http://my.client").unwrap(),
        }
    }

    pub fn get_resource_a(&mut self, id: String) -> ResourceA {
        let params = ("a", id);
        self.client.get(params).unwrap()
    }

    pub fn get_resource_a2(&mut self, id: String) -> ResourceA {
        let params = ("a2", id);
        let response: Response<ResourceA> = self.api_client.get(params).unwrap();
        response.data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a response with two variants, so an enum based solution may be considered:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct ResourceA {
    value: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Response {
    ErrAndValue{error: bool, data: ResourceA},
    Simple(ResourceA),
}
```

I've used the [untagged](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) annotation to conform the json format:

```
{ value: "resource A" }
{ error: false, data: { value: "resource A" } }
```

Then your `RestPath` impl reduce to:

```
impl<'a> RestPath<(&'a str, String)> for Response {
    fn get_path(params: (&str, String)) -> Result<String, Error> {
        let (resource, id) = params;
        Ok(format!("{}/{}", resource, id))
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking on using a `enum`, but I didn't know about `untagged`, which is the key part.

How could I access the `ResourceA` data after getting the response?

Comment: Use pattern match via `match`, see [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a9d6228e79b03cceaf2b38da596fdc87&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015). Anyway, a nice place to see for rust patterns is [Rust by examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/enum.html#enums)

Comment: Thank you. I realized later that it was the way to get it